# What is new alternative for CryptQueryObject because it is deprecated

Tags: c++, certificate, digital-signature

I am using cryptQueryObject to get handle to store and crypt msg.
as this is deprecated I would like to know whats alternative for it.

Thanks
Vibhor

Comment: I guess CPGetKeyParam and/or CPGetProvParam ... presumably you will have to update your set up and use only next generation APIs.

Comment: Can you share a minimal working example?

Comment: Hi I have used code mentioned in    https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323809/how-to-get-information-from-authenticode-signed-executables for finding issuer name in the certificate, but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptqueryobject mentions that cryptQueryObject is deprecated, so not sure what is the alternative for it.